# How can I combine two wall switches into one?

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch

As you can see in the picture the top switch doesn’t work at all. The bottom switch is the one that actually works.

How can I change this 2 switches to just 1 - when I would buy a brand new one

Please help on this!!!

[image]

Comment: Can you post a photo that clearly shows the back of the box please?

Comment: Welcome!   Do you know where the red wire goes, or what it is supposed to turn on?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the black and red wires that are connected to the same side of the switch power either light fixtures or standard outlets...

1. Mark the wire that's on the side by itself with tape or something else.
2. Remove all wires from the switch.
3. Clip the loops off the two unmarked wires, then strip them 1/2" to expose fresh wire.
4. Use a suitably sized wire nut to combine those two wires, along with a 6" length of #14 or #12 solid copper building wire.
5. Bend a loop into the pigtail wire using a needle-nose plier or similar.
6. Install the two loops onto either screw of a standard two-way switch, wrapping the loop clockwise under the screw head. The loop should fit snugly against the screw shaft and wrap at least half way around.
7. Install the switch and a cover plate into the box, tucking the wires in carefully so as not to kink them.

Comment: I don't usually clip the wires stranded wired can be straightened and wirenutted. Other than that +

Comment: Sure. I guess I'm paranoid about fatigue and corrosion.

Answer (score 0):

Since that is a duplex switch it performs 2 functions or handles 2 lighting circuits. If you want both functions to be controlled from 1 switch just combine the 2 wires going out of the switch. A picture of the other side of the switch is necessary to see how the whole circuit is wired.